# Spring Boot not letting go of tomcat.jdbc.pool connections through spring integration amqp inbound-channel-adaptor

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, spring-amqp

I am just betting there is something fundamental I am missing about this but for the life of me I have not been able to figure it out. I am attempting to use Spring Integration to receive from an amqp:inbound-channel-adaptor, which ends up calling a service that invokes an Oracle stored procedure using "jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql).execute();"

Have all this running through a Spring Boot application that includes the spring-boot-starter-web, so it pulls in embedded tomcat and my Spring Boot app also includes spring-boot-starter-amqp, spring-boot-starter-integration, spring-boot-starter-jdbc so to let Spring Boot do all the magic for me... SB ROCKS!

I did have to also specifically include spring-integration-amqp in my pom.xml file in order to use XML for some reason:

```
    <!-- Required in order to expose amqp xml schema namespace -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Everything appears to work fine; however, it appears that the channel is not letting go of the JDBC connection. I eventually get a org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException. This happens as soon as the channel has serviced 'spring.datasource.max-active' messages from the queue. I confirmed this by playing with that property and it always happens at whatever number I set it to. I log the service method called in the service-activator after it is done with the db call so I know they complete but the db connection apparently never gets handed back to the pool... Any ideas? Here is the relevant snippets from my project:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:@[myserver].com:1521:[SID]
spring.datasource.username = scrubbed
spring.datasource.password = scrubbed
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.max-active=50 
...
spring.rabbitmq.port = 5672
spring.rabbitmq.addresses = clusered.server1, clusered.server1
spring.rabbitmq.username = scrubbed
spring.rabbitmq.password = scrubbed
```

Service:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public void executeDbJob(String dbProcedureCall) {
    log.info("Executing Job id: {} Database Call: {}", jobId, dbProcedureCall);
    executeStoredProcedure(dbProcedureCall);
    log.info("Finished DB call for job id: {} Database Call: {}", jobId, dbProcedureCall);
}
/**
 * This wraps a stored procedure call just as it is, parameter values included into an anonymous
 * pl/sql block. This could be a pretty big security issue so we will want to scrub the
 * procedure coming in to ensure it doesn't have additional embedded SQL.
 */
private void executeStoredProcedure(final String procedure) {
    final String sql = "begin ".concat(procedure).concat(" end;");
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql).execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.error("Could not execute procedure call: {} raised: {}", sql, e);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:amqp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp" 
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/amqp/spring-integration-amqp.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd"
    default-lazy-init="false">

    <beans:description>Recommendation Engine provider account event flow</beans:description>

    <!-- ********** Consumer flows ********** -->

    <!-- Note: The rabbitConnectionFactory is setup automagically just like rabbitTemplate by spring-boot-starter-amqp -->
    <amqp:inbound-channel-adapter id="initiateJobRequest" channel="initiateJobRequestChannel"
        message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" queue-names="bc.initiate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
        auto-startup="true" concurrent-consumers="1" acknowledge-mode="AUTO" error-handler="loggingErrorHandler" task-executor="amqpClientExecutor"/>

    <!-- Add queue capacity to make channel pollable -->
    <channel id="initiateJobRequestChannel">
        <queue capacity="32" />
        <interceptors>
            <wire-tap channel="amqpDebugLogger" />
        </interceptors>
    </channel>

     <service-activator id="initiateJobRequestExtractor" input-channel="initiateJobRequestChannel"
        output-channel="nullChannel" ref="jobExecutorService" method="executeDbJob">
        <poller ref="initiateJobPoller" />
    </service-activator>

    <!-- ********** Loggers ********** -->

     <logging-channel-adapter id="amqpDebugLogger" level="DEBUG" auto-startup="true"
        log-full-message="true" />


    <!-- ********** Executors ********** -->

     <task:executor id="amqpClientExecutor" pool-size="8" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

    <poller id="initiateJobPoller" task-executor="initiateJobTaskExecutor" fixed-rate="50" receive-timeout="1000" />
    <task:executor id="initiateJobTaskExecutor" pool-size="16" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

</beans:beans>
```

Adding the exception blah in case it is helpful:

```
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolExhaustedException: [initiateJobTaskExecutor-5] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 30 seconds, none available[size:50; busy:50; idle:0; lastwait:30000].
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:186)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at com.everbridge.bce.jobexecutor.service.impl.JobExecutorServiceImpl.executeStoredProcedure(JobExecutorServiceImpl.java:90)
    at com.everbridge.bce.jobexecutor.service.impl.JobExecutorServiceImpl.executeDbJob(JobExecutorServiceImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:102)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:330)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluateExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:164)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:276)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:142)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:99)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:219)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:146)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:298)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It's generally a good idea to add "answer" this question to show users it has a solution, rather than just adding a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out... Kudos go out to Pavel Horal for his response to Mark's question about "C3PO connection pooling - connections not being released" (and Mark for asking it), which gave me a clue on what was my issue and how to fix it. Turns out it is because I am asking for a database connection from JdbcTemplate (`jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(sql).execute()`); I replaced it with `jdbcTemplate.update(sql);` and it *worked*!